# ssh seems to be trying to use a .ssh/rsa_opay file for publickey authentication. Why is this and what is it?

Tags: openssh

I set up an rsa key in .ssh on an IBM iSeries(V7R4) using OpenSSH_8.0p1. Running `ssh -vT git@github.com`. I get "debug1: Will attempt key: /home//.ssh/id_rsa_opay". There is no such file. There is a .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub. Why is ssh trying to use this id_rsa_opay file?

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.113.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/BHAYESDEV/.ssh/id_rsa_opay type -1
debug1: identity file /home/BHAYESDEV/.ssh/id_rsa_opay-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-c89ab1f3
debug1: no match: babeld-c89ab1f3
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa_opay 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa_opay
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Recreated the id_rsa key pair. Retried the ssh -vT git@github. Same result

Comment: Also asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1476475/321059)

Answer (score 0):

For the usage of other functions on the system the global ssh_config was changed to have an IdentityFile entry of ~/.ssh/id_ras_opay; \